# how to best ignore free domain emails for sending a pdf via email(python)

Tags: python, email

I need to send a certain pdf to corporate users who fill out a form and not to users to use public domain email addresses like gmail. This is not spam email, users are filling out a form to get the pdf in email. Form mentions to use company email id, but some people still register using their personal email address.

Questions:

What is the best way to achieve this?  I am using following and this keeps getting big as I add more providers:

"if "gmail" in sender_address or "hotmail" in sender_address or "yahoo" in sender_address or "aol.com" in sender_address:"

Comment: Don't want to sound nasty, but this sounds like you are trying to spam corporate users... or...?

Comment: By "public domain" you presumably mean "free"? Because gmail isn't public domain, nor is yahoo mail, aol mail, ...

Comment: its only for users who fill out the form to download the pdf, so no spam. Form mentions to use company email id, but we still get few requests with @gmail etc.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` in conjunction with a `list`, this is an *example*, don't use this in production, it might break.

```
list = ['gmail', 'aol', 'hotmail', 'yahoo']
myemail = 'foo@aol.com'
if mystring.split('@')[1].split('.')[0] in list:
    print 'I`m public'
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse e-mail addresses, I'd look at some [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) that has been tested to reduce the risk of a parsing error.

To filter users by domain, I'd add all the domains that you want to filter to a set and check using the `in` operator (this should be more efficient than checking a `list`).

Finally, as @mac pointed out, it would be probably better to let your users subscribe to the newsletter (or whatever you want to send), rather than sending them unsolicited e-mail.